# .profile file loaded on starting VSCode

Tags: shell-script, profile, visual-studio-code

in my .profile i have these two lines

> daemon plank

> daemon autokey

what these basically do is start plank(dock application) and autokey(custom shortcut maker) on startup,
it is working fine but the problem is when I open VSCode autokey also opens this means that .profile is loaded.

Now how to do it properly so that they run only when the linux is started-up.

Comment: Read `man pgrep`. You can detect that the daemons are running.

Comment: the problem is only thisi that whenever you open autokey once it starts running in the background when you open it twice than it opens in GUI mode which i don't want.                           therefore whenever i open VS Code autokey window also opens

Comment: `.profile` runs when you log in. It can run multiple times if you log in on multiple consoles or via SSH. It shouldn't run when an application such as Vscode starts, this may be a bug in Vscode. In any case, these are GUI-related services, so they shouldn't run from `.profile` (which runs on login) but as GUI startup applications (the easiest way for that depends on your desktop environment).